# .VSMDI Error in VS TFS 2008

Tags: c#, .net

I have deleted a test from unit test and so need to checkin the .vsmdi file but it still gives error regarding that deleted test method.

any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting it, it should automatically be created again afterwards..